# SQL "Log Bytes Flushed/sec" counter from powershell Error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, counter, azure-performancecounters

I am trying to calculate the type of AZURE SQL I need using this: http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/ => http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/Downloads/sql-perfmon.zip

This is a PowerShell script that gets data from some counters from SQL but it errors out when accessing the "Log Bytes Flushed/sec" counter that it is pressent in SQL when I run

```
select *  FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters where counter_name like 'Log Bytes Flushed/sec%'
```

the error I get from PowerShell is:

> Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer. At
>   C:\users\ringhel\desktop\sql-perfmon.ps1:47 char:1
>   + Get-Counter -Counter $counters -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 3600 |
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

The error comes from this variable:

> $counters = @("\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",
>   "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Reads/sec", "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Writes/sec",
>
> "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Read Bytes/sec", "\LogicalDisk(C:)\Disk Write Bytes/sec", "\SQLSERVER:Databases($DatabaseName)\Log
>   Bytes Flushed/sec")

After searching the web, instead of SQLSERVER I tried MSSQLSERVER (this is the instance name of the SQL server), MSSQL'$MSSQLSERVER and MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER but the same error.

Please help.

Comment: Start Perfmon on the server and find the counter you want and you'll see the name, instance name, etc...

Comment: I started perfmon on the server, that is how I got the error saying that the counter does not exist even though the counter exists in sql as I pointed out in the description.

Comment: i found the counter in perfmon, but I still get the same error, even thought the counter exists

Answer (score 1):

found the problem.
I had to set the execution policy for the LocalMachine to RemoteSigned. It was Undefined.

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine

Answer (score 0):

My issue was slightly different.  For a named instance I had to define the SQL Server counter like this:

```
\MSSQL`$SQL2016:Databases(_Total)\Log Bytes Flushed/sec
```

My instance was named "SQL2016".  The back tick escapes the `$` in the instance name.